# Botium-core unable to load custom asserter

Tags: botium-box

I recently updated the dependencies in my test project. After updating, botium-core is unable to load the custom asserters I had defined.

Here is a snippet of package.json that shows my dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
"botium-connector-dialogflow": "^0.0.25",
"botium-core": "^1.11.0",
"jsonpath": "^1.1.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.20",
"minimist": "^1.2.5",
"mocha": "^8.2.1"}
```

Here is a snippet of botium.json

```
{
"botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
        "PROJECTNAME": "my-project",
        "CONTAINERMODE": "dialogflow",
        "DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID": "<google project id>",
        "DIALOGFLOW_CLIENT_EMAIL": "<service credentials email>",
        "DIALOGFLOW_PRIVATE_KEY": "<service credentials private key>",
        "ASSERTERS": [
            {
                "ref": "ASSERTER1",
                "src": "./src/asserter1.js"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Sources": {},
    "Envs": {}
}
```

I also switched the path to .\src\asserter1.js, and it works on my windows machine, but fails in a linux build env.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [the Github issue tracker](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/issues/607) for the resolution. Bug has been fixed now.